# Download file / installer jar which is part of war from tomcat server (window and linux)

Tags: java, windows, war, tomcat8

I was facing problem to download installer jar from war deployed on tomcat server on window machine. The code was working on linux machine but not on window machine.

```
   public Response downloadPOST(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    long length = 0;
    byte[] data;
    try {
        WebApplicationContext context = (WebApplicationContext) WebApplicationContextProvider
                .getApplicationContext();

        String sPath = context.getServletContext()
                .getResource("/installer/installer-" + Version.VERSION + ".jar").getPath();

        java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(sPath);

        data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        length = data.length;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error( e);
        throw new WebApplicationException("File Not Found !!");
    }
    StreamingOutput fileStream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(java.io.OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try {
                output.write(data);
                output.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error( e);
                throw new WebApplicationException("File Not Found !!");
            }
        }
    };
    return Response.ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename = installer-" + Version.VERSION + ".jar")
            .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(length)).build();
}
```

The above code was throwing NoSuchFileException due to special character  and prefix '/' in file path on window machine.

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%208.0\webapps\ROOT\installer\installer-x.x.x.jar
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: I had problem but i couldn't find solution on stackoverflow. so posted problem with solution.

Comment: better to post solution as answer

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by using UrlDecoder and using regular expression to remove prefix '/' from url.

The code which is working for window and linux machine

```
    public Response downloadPOST(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    long length = 0;
    byte[] data;
    try {
        WebApplicationContext context = (WebApplicationContext) WebApplicationContextProvider
                .getApplicationContext();

        String sPath = context.getServletContext()
                .getResource("/installer/installer-" + AgentVersion.STRING_VERSION + ".jar").getPath();

        sPath = URLDecoder.decode(sPath, "utf-8");
        // get the right path on Windows or Linux on any drive letter
        // window : if the beginning of the string is a slash, then a
        // character, then a colon and another slash, replace it with the
        // character, the colon, and the slash (leaving the leading slash
        // off).
        sPath = sPath.replaceFirst("^/(.:/)", "$1");

        java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(sPath);

        data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        length = data.length;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " at " + request.getRequestURI(), e);
        throw new WebApplicationException("File Not Found !!");
    }
    StreamingOutput fileStream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(java.io.OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try {
                output.write(data);
                output.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " at " + request.getRequestURI(), e);
                throw new WebApplicationException("File Not Found !!");
            }
        }
    };
    return Response.ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename = installer-" + Version.VERSION + ".jar")
            .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(length)).build();
}
```